# SQLite outer join column filtering

Tags: sqlite, left-join

As a training exercise I'm working on a fictional SQLite database resembling League of Legends, and I need to perform a left outer join to get a table of all players and if they have skins that are not called `'Classic'`, return those too.

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM players
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM playerchampions WHERE NOT championskin = 'Classic')
            ON name = playername
```

Which returns what I am looking for, but also a lot of columns I don't want (player experience, player IP, player RP, playername in the `playerchampions` table. The code for the two tables is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE players ( 
    name       TEXT    PRIMARY KEY,
    experience INTEGER,
    currencyip INTEGER,
    currencyrp INTEGER 
);
CREATE TABLE playerchampions ( 
    playername   TEXT REFERENCES players ( name ) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    championname TEXT REFERENCES champions ( name ) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    championskin TEXT REFERENCES skins ( skinname ) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY ( playername, championname, championskin ) 
);
```

As I said, the query executes, but I can't use SELECT players.name, playerchampions.championname, playerchampions.championskin as the playerchampions columns are not given their proper table name when returned.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using aliases:

```
SELECT p.name, c.championskin FROM players p LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT pc.playername playername, pc.championskin championskin FROM playerchampions pc WHERE NOT pc.championskin = 'Classic') c ON p.name = c.playername;
```

Not sure if its exactly what you need, but it will get you closer...

Comment: Thanks, that was the trick indeed, just needed c.championname too

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM players p LEFT OUTER JOIN playerchampions pc ON (p.name = pc.playername)     WHERE NOT pc.championskin = 'Classic'
```

Comment: replacing SELECT * with SELECT p.name, pc.championname, pc.championskin did it for me. Thanks a lot!